# Render first element of a multivalued field

Tags: theming, 8

On my site I've an image field, multi value.
I would like, on a custom view mode, to display only the first image. On the field formatter I don't have this option.

How should I do this? Directly from twig or I've to use a preprocess function?

[EDIT] I would to do this without using a custom node template :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then it's

```
{{ content.field_name[0] }}
```

> **Note**: If you need to print the label use `{{ content.field_name['#title'] }}` as `{{ content.field_name[0] }}` does
>   not print the label.

Comment: No, I'm not using views, I'm working on node template.

Comment: @arrubiu updated answer

Comment: Ok, works :) And it was simple to imagine it ;)

Comment: @arrubiu if you need the label of the image field use `{{ content.field_name['#title'] }}` as `{{ content.field_name[0] }}` does not print the label.

Answer (score 1):

There are now a couple of modules which look like they could help.

https://www.drupal.org/project/single_image_formatter

> This module provides formatters for Image, Media and Responsive image
> field, that displays only first value of multi-valued fields. It is
> useful, when you configure teasers display and don't need to show all
> images.

https://www.drupal.org/project/field_formatter_range

> The Field Formatter Range module provides the option to display only
> selected range of values for multivalued entity fields.